# Steam Auth with Open ID (Symfony 4.x)

Tags: php, symfony, steam

I'm trying to use two methods to authenticate in my website:

1. Using email address / password (working)
2. Using Steam (where I have a problem)

Here's my `services.yaml`:

```
security:
  encoders:
    App\Entity\User\User:
      algorithm: bcrypt
  providers:
    user_provider:
      entity:
        class: App\Entity\User\User
    steam_provider:
      id: App\Security\SteamAuth\User\SteamUserProvider
    chain_provider:
      chain:
        providers: [user_provider, steam_provider]
  firewalls:
    dev:
      pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
      security: false
    steam:
      anonymous: ~
      pattern: /steam/login
      user_checker: App\Security\User\UserChecker
      provider: steam_provider
      steam: true
      logout:
        path:   /logout
        target: /
    classic:
      anonymous: true
      user_checker: App\Security\User\UserChecker
      provider: user_provider
      form_login:
        provider: user_provider
        default_target_path: /servers
        use_referer: true
        login_path: /login
        check_path: /login
        username_parameter: login_form[emailAddress]
        password_parameter: login_form[password]
      remember_me:
        remember_me_parameter: login_form[remember_me]
        secret: '%kernel.secret%'
        lifetime: 1209600 # 2 week in seconds
        path: /
      logout:
        target: /
  access_control:
    # Users
    - { path: '^/steam/login', roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Compared to other services, Steam offers authentication only with OpenID. There's no problem, I updated my code to work OpenID.

In my opinion, everything works fine, even token is correctly. The main problem is after reloading page. Auth token is lost and I'm authenticated as Anonymous user. As you see, I redirect users to `/login` no matter what (I have logic to redirect from that page if user is authenticated).

Here's my code:

`SteamListener.php`

```
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Security\SteamAuth\Firewall;

use App\Security\SteamAuth\Authentication\Token\SteamUserToken;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\RequestEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\AuthenticationManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;

/**
 * Class SteamListener
 * @package App\Security\SteamAuth\Firewall
 */
class SteamListener
{
    /**
     * @var AuthenticationManagerInterface
     */
    private $authenticationManager;

    /**
     * @var RouterInterface
     */
    private $router;

    /**
     * @var TokenStorageInterface
     */
    private $tokenStorage;

    /**
     * SteamListener constructor.
     *
     * @param AuthenticationManagerInterface $authenticationManager
     * @param TokenStorageInterface          $tokenStorage
     * @param RouterInterface                $router
     */
    public function __construct(AuthenticationManagerInterface $authenticationManager, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage, RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->authenticationManager = $authenticationManager;
        $this->tokenStorage          = $tokenStorage;
        $this->router                = $router;
    }

    /**
     * Try to authenticate user based on SteamID.
     *
     * @param RequestEvent $event
     */
    public function __invoke(RequestEvent $event)
    {
        $request   = $event->getRequest();
        $claimedId = str_replace('https://steamcommunity.com/openid/id/', '', $request->query->get('openid_claimed_id'));

        try {
            $token = new SteamUserToken($claimedId);
            $token->setAttributes($request->query->all());

            $authToken = $this->authenticationManager->authenticate($token);
            $this->tokenStorage->setToken($authToken);
        } catch (AuthenticationException $exception) {
            $token = $this->tokenStorage->getToken();
            if ($token instanceof SteamUserToken) {
                $this->tokenStorage->setToken(null);
            }
        }

        $event->setResponse(new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('login')));
    }
}
```

`SteamProvider.php`

```
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Security\SteamAuth\Authentication\Provider;

use App\Security\SteamAuth\Authentication\Token\SteamUserToken;
use Symfony\Component\HttpClient\HttpClient;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Provider\AuthenticationProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\Exception\ClientExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\Exception\RedirectionExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\Exception\ServerExceptionInterface;
use Symfony\Contracts\HttpClient\Exception\TransportExceptionInterface;

/**
 * Class SteamProvider
 * @package App\Security\SteamAuth\Provider
 */
class SteamProvider implements AuthenticationProviderInterface
{
    const ACCEPTED_RESPONSE = "ns:http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0\nis_valid:true\n";

    /**
     * This actually points to UserRepository.
     *
     * @var UserProviderInterface
     */
    private $userProvider;

    /**
     * SteamProvider constructor.
     *
     * @param UserProviderInterface $userProvider
     */
    public function __construct(UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $this->userProvider = $userProvider;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     *
     * Note: Token is an instance of SteamUserToken.
     */
    public function authenticate(TokenInterface $token)
    {
        if (!$user = $this->userProvider->loadUserByUsername($token->getUsername())) {
            throw new AuthenticationException('Steam auth is invalid!');
        }

        if ($token->getAttribute('openid_ns') !== 'http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0') {
            throw new AuthenticationException('Steam token is invalid!');
        }

        // Validate SteamID before authenticating user.
        $checkAuth                = $token->getAttributes();
        $checkAuth['openid_mode'] = 'check_authentication';

        try {
            $request  = HttpClient::create();
            $response = $request->request(Request::METHOD_GET, $checkAuth['openid_op_endpoint'], ['query' => $checkAuth]);
            if ($response->getContent() !== self::ACCEPTED_RESPONSE) {
                throw new AuthenticationException('Steam token is invalid!');
            }

            $authToken = new SteamUserToken($token->getUsername(), $user->getRoles());
            $authToken->setUser($user);

            return $authToken;
        } catch (ClientExceptionInterface|RedirectionExceptionInterface|ServerExceptionInterface|TransportExceptionInterface $e) {
            throw new AuthenticationException('Steam token is invalid!');
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function supports(TokenInterface $token)
    {
        return $token instanceof SteamUserToken;
    }
}
```

`SteamUserToken.php`

```
<?php declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace App\Security\SteamAuth\Authentication\Token;

use App\Entity\User\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

/**
 * Class SteamUserToken
 * @package App\Security\SteamAuth\Authentication
 */
class SteamUserToken implements TokenInterface
{
    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $attributes = [];

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    private $authenticated = false;

    /**
     * @var User|null
     */
    private $user = null;

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    private $roles = [];

    /**
     * @var string|null
     */
    private $steamId = null;

    /**
     * SteamUserToken constructor.
     *
     * @param string $steamId
     * @param array  $roles
     */
    public function __construct(string $steamId, array $roles = [])
    {
        $this->steamId       = $steamId;
        $this->roles         = $roles;
        $this->authenticated = \count($roles) > 0;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     * @var $user UserInterface
     */
    public function setUser($user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }


    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->steamId;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getRoles()
    {
        if (!$this->user) {
            return [];
        }

        return $this->roles;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $roles
     */
    public function setRoles(array $roles = [])
    {
        $this->roles = $roles;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getRoleNames()
    {
        return array_map(function ($role) {return $role;}, $this->user ? $this->user->getRoles() : []);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getCredentials()
    {
        return '';
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function isAuthenticated()
    {
        return $this->authenticated;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function setAuthenticated($authenticated)
    {
        $this->authenticated = $authenticated;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        if ($this->getUser() instanceof UserInterface) {
            $this->getUser()->eraseCredentials();
        }
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function serialize()
    {
        return serialize($this->__serialize());
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function __serialize(): array
    {
        return [$this->attributes, $this->authenticated, $this->steamId, $this->roles, $this->user];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function unserialize($serialized)
    {
        $this->__unserialize(unserialize($serialized));
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function __unserialize(array $data): void
    {
        [$this->attributes, $this->authenticated, $this->steamId, $this->roles, $this->user] = $data;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getAttributes()
    {
        return $this->attributes;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function setAttributes(array $attributes)
    {
        $this->attributes = $attributes;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function hasAttribute($name)
    {
        return \array_key_exists($name, $this->attributes);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getAttribute($name)
    {
        if (!\array_key_exists($name, $this->attributes)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('This token has no "%s" attribute.', $name));
        }

        return $this->attributes[$name];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function setAttribute($name, $value)
    {
        $this->attributes[$name] = $value;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        if (!$this->user) {
            return '-';
        }

        return $this->user->getUsername();
    }
}
```

If I'm writing `return;` after setting `$this->tokenStorage->setToken($authToken)` inside `SteamListener`, I'm getting an error, but that's the curious thing: I'm authenticated correctly in that page (see attached photo). Otherwise, I'm redirected to login page. (Instead of throwing error in that method I called `$this->getUser()` and returned me the authenticated user. Also, I tried to redirect user to another page and the problem still persists).

[image: error]

EDIT: Here's my console log:

```
2019-10-30T14:32:47+01:00 [debug] Stored the security token in the session.
2019-10-30T14:32:47+01:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sonata\BlockBundle\Cache\HttpCacheHandler::onKernelResponse".
2019-10-30T14:32:47+01:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse".
2019-10-30T14:32:47+01:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelResponse".
2019-10-30T14:32:47+01:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\Security\Http\RememberMe\ResponseListener::onKernelResponse".
2019-10-30T14:32:47+01:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelResponse".
2019-10-30T14:32:47+01:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelResponse".
2019-10-30T14:32:47+01:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\EventListener\WebDebugToolbarListener::onKernelResponse".
2019-10-30T14:32:47+01:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\DisallowRobotsIndexingListener::onResponse".
2019-10-30T14:32:47+01:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SessionListener::onKernelResponse".
2019-10-30T14:32:47+01:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.response" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\StreamedResponseListener::onKernelResponse".
2019-10-30T14:32:47+01:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleListener::onKernelFinishRequest".
2019-10-30T14:32:47+01:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\SessionListener::onFinishRequest".
2019-10-30T14:32:47+01:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener::onKernelFinishRequest".
2019-10-30T14:32:47+01:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SecurityBundle\Debug\TraceableFirewallListener::onKernelFinishRequest".
2019-10-30T14:32:47+01:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.finish_request" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\LocaleAwareListener::onKernelFinishRequest".
2019-10-30T14:32:47+01:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\SwiftmailerBundle\EventListener\EmailSenderListener::onTerminate".
2019-10-30T14:32:47+01:00 [debug] Notified event "kernel.terminate" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\ProfilerListener::onKernelTerminate".
[Wed Oct 30 15:32:47 2019] 127.0.0.1:52654 [302]: /steam/login?openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fopenid%2Flogin&openid.claimed_id=https%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fopenid%2Fid%2F
76561198062372939&openid.identity=https%3A%2F%2Fsteamcommunity.com%2Fopenid%2Fid%2F76561198062372939&openid.return_to=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fsteam%2Flogin&openid.response_nonce=2019-10-30T13%3A31%3A49ZSGUwWiQNPgQRCry3p3AjonwB7rg%3D&openid.assoc_handle=1234567890
&openid.signed=signed%2Cop_endpoint%2Cclaimed_id%2Cidentity%2Creturn_to%2Cresponse_nonce%2Cassoc_handle&openid.sig=3ysTtN3Cc3FbC8b0oWi8ZTCrc0U%3D
2019-10-30T14:32:49+01:00 [info] User Deprecated: The Symfony\Bundle\TwigBundle\Loader\FilesystemLoader class is deprecated since version 4.3 and will be removed in 5.0; use Twig notation for templates instead.
2019-10-30T14:32:49+01:00 [info] Matched route "login".
2019-10-30T14:32:49+01:00 [info] Populated the TokenStorage with an anonymous Token.
```

Comment: I just had a glance over it, and you've already mentioned the area that looks a bit suspicious to me - the `SteamListener::__invoke` method. To me it seems strange that you'd always be setting a redirect response to the login page at the bottom of that method, but based on that I would expect a `return` after setting the token to work. However you've already said that it doesn't. Does it have any impact if you put a conditional around the `$event->setResponse()` call in that method? For example `if (!$token) { // set redirect response`

Comment: Thank you for reply! Let me explain why I use `__invoke` instead of `handle`. Starting with Symfony 4.3, that interface was declared as deprecated. Now, let me see if I understood correctly. You want me to do something like this: https://pastebin.com/gZVczZCZ

Comment: @mickadoo One more thing to add. If I'm adding `return;` after I'm setting the token, I'm getting redirected my custom controller :: method. There's only one row: `throw new Exception("If you reached this page, please contact the administrator!");`. I commented that line and I'm dumping current user and guess what? It shows my account! After I change page, everything is lost. Any idea? Maybe my serialization is bad? Or firewall?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you replied to me. I'm not 100% familiar with the steam authentication, but when I used OAuth services it stored the token in local storage on the client side and then included it in each subsequent request. The token was stored in the database with an expiration date. Are you doing something like that?

Comment: @mickadoo I'm not using database to store my session token. I'm using system local files as Symfony uses by default.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't too clear about that - what do you mean by "system local files"?

Comment: @mickadoo I wanted to say that I didn't change default folder for sessions and sessions are still written in default folder which is `/tmp` (if I'm not wrong)